Green's function for 3D rectangular box with Neumann boundary conditions
Is there an explicit expression for the Green's function for Laplace's equation on a bounded cartesian domain in $\Bbb R^3$ with Neumann boundary conditions?
Magnetostatics.$\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{div\!} \DeclareMathOperator{\grad}{grad}$ Trying to find the "potential" magnetic field given an arbitrary 3D magnetic field $B$ ($\Div B=0$). The potential field satisfies $B = \grad \varphi$ and so the solenoidal constraint $\Div B=0$ yields
$$
\nabla^2 \varphi=0.
$$
Moreover we have $n\cdot B$ on each boundary and so have the Neumann boundary conditions
$$
n\cdot \grad\varphi = n\cdot B.
$$
I already have a code that performs 3D integration of free space Green's function (Helmholtz decomposition), so I want to use the apparatus of that code to help solve this problem. However, I need to use the correct Green's function.
